# Unable to find the JSON file path in Azure DevOps Pipeline which is created for ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to create Azure resources with ARM template using Azure PowerShell Pipeline.

My two ARM template JSON files are stored in the same directory where the YAML file and Powershell files are stored

Here is the code of the Powershell file

```
param (
    
    #Name of the Resource Group of the Image Gallery
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $deploymentName,

    #Name of the Image Gallery
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $rgName
)
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deploymentName -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
  -TemplateFile '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Deploy.json' `
  -TemplateParameterFile '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DeployParameters.json'
```

Here is the code of the YAML file

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger: none

pool: 'Default'
  #vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- script: echo Create, Shared Image Gallery!
  displayName: 'Run a multiline-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription – MPN(08f41212-2053-434e-b4b3-ace08XXXXXX)'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Deploy_New.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: -deploymentName "WVD"  -rgName "WVDRG"
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    pwsh: true
```

Here is the error I am getting, I am using self-hosted agent pool running in Windows Server 2019 and PowerShell Core.

```
020-09-15T15:41:38.8359249Z ##[section]Starting: AzurePowerShell
2020-09-15T15:41:38.8615322Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-15T15:41:38.8615818Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
2020-09-15T15:41:38.8616217Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
2020-09-15T15:41:38.8616582Z Version      : 5.173.1
2020-09-15T15:41:38.8616919Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-15T15:41:38.8617547Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurepowershelltroubleshooting
2020-09-15T15:41:38.8617935Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-15T15:41:40.0811736Z Generating script.
2020-09-15T15:41:40.1352322Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-09-15T15:41:40.1634699Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\1d73a74d-12ca-470b-bd53-c23358ee4e2d.ps1'"
2020-09-15T15:41:41.5971906Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2020-09-15T15:41:41.7815293Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\1.9.3\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2020-09-15T15:41:42.3907347Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2020-09-15T15:41:42.7014316Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2020-09-15T15:41:43.3364066Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2020-09-15T15:41:45.2061727Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 08f41212-2053-434e-b4b3-XXXXX -TenantId ***
2020-09-15T15:41:47.5198572Z ##[error]Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot find path 'C:\agent\_work\3\s\$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\DeployHostPool.json' because it does not exist.
2020-09-15T15:41:47.6342141Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-09-15T15:41:48.1235457Z ##[section]Finishing: AzurePowerShell
```

Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap those `'` single quotes for double-quotes, `"` in `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`.

In PowerShell, double quotes will allow for `String Expansion` which is what you want, in order to use string expansion syntax like this:

```
"This computer is called $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
PS>This computer is called eLope
```

When you use single quotes, it will always give you a string literal, like so:

```
'This computer is called $($env:COMPUTERNAME)'
PS>This computer is called $($env:COMPUTERNAME)
```

Comment: It works like a champ, thanks for the quick reply. You have a good day ahead.